# How to get bodies to not scroll while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on a website for the past few weeks and i've run into a problem. I have a header centered then body called .content a few inches underneath. The problem is that they both scroll when I scroll and i'd rather that not be a thing.

```html
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin:0px;
    background:#000;
}
.header-cont {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.header {
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.content {
    width:960px;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    height: 4000px;
    margin: 70px auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well as the CSS you've posted, please.

Comment: Try removing `position:fixed;` from the div you don't need scrolling for.

Comment: There's a lot of code and it won't let me have "", and changing it from fixed screws up the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a fixed header with a scrolling body. Your CSS is right this far as it works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      background: #000;
    }
    
    .header-cont {
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
    }
    
    .header {
      height: 50px;
      background: #99ff00;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      width: 960px;
      margin: 0px auto;
    }
    
    .content {
      width: 960px;
      background: #33ff99;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      height: 4000px;
      margin: 70px auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header-cont">
    <div class="header">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">test test test</div>
</body>

</html>
```

could it be that you got your .header-cont class at the wrong position?